# how to automatically delete channels with a discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, runtime-error, discord.py

I'm doing a python bot for discord. it create an delete channel according to player instructions. 
I want to create a garbage collector that test all the server.channels and delete the outdated one.

I do :

```
async def waitTimer():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

        regex = re.compile(r"[0-9]*_[a-z0-9]*-[0-9]*") #nom des channels de raid

        for cCurrent in client.get_all_channels():
            if regex.match(cCurrent.name):
                numRaid = int(cCurrent.name[0])
                cRaidCurrent = cRaids[numRaid]
                date = datetime.datetime.now()
                print (cRaidCurrent.raid.fin.timestamp())
                print (date.timestamp())
                if cRaidCurrent.raid.fin < date:
                    if cRaidCurrent.retirerRaid():
                        cId = cRaidCurrent.com.id
                        await removeFromListe(cRaidCurrent)
                        await client.delete_channel(client.get_channel(cId))
                        cCurrent = 0
```

Sometimes it pass and sometimes I get this error :

```
    for cCurrent in client.get_all_channels():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 581,
 in get_all_channels
    for channel in server.channels:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

If I understand it clearly the `client.get_all_channels` is a dictionary and I can't remove the channels during the iteration ... So the question is what other possibilities do I have to remove those channel ?

Comment: iterate over `get_all_channels` and build a list of channels to be removed, then remove those channels in a separate loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) for the answer that work perfectly.

In the end the deleting operation needs to be done in 2 times. Here is the code if anyone needs it :

```py
for cCurrent in client.get_all_channels():
    if regex.match(cCurrent.name):
        numRaid = getNumChannel(cCurrent.name)
        cRaidCurrent = cRaids[numRaid]
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if cRaidCurrent.raid.fin < now:
            toDelete.append(cRaidCurrent)

for cRaidCurrent in toDelete:
    cId = cRaidCurrent.id
    cRaidCurrent.retirerRaid()
    await removeCRaid(cRaidCurrent)
    del cRaids[cId]
```